# Детский вопрос: куда ходит доходяга?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов, просторечия

У нас в доме живет совсем старый пес. Однажды я назвала его доходягой.
Девочка (семь лет) спросила: "Почему — доходяга?" Попыталась объяснить ассоциативно: трудяга — тот, кто много трудится, работяга — тот, кто много работает.
Последовало удивленное детское мнение: значит, он много ходит? (А собака худенькая, горбатая, еле передвигается.)

В словаре Ефремовой:
**доходяга**, м. и ж., разг.-сниж. Изможденный, обессилевший человек или животное.

Подскажите, как доходчиво объяснить ребенку значение и использование этого слова?
А со мной, пожалуйста, поделитесь своим знанием этимологии.

Comment: К сожалению, нет времени на ответ. Ограничусь комментарием. В передаче "Как это по-русски?" от 2 июля 2015 г.  на вопрос о происхождении  слова _доходяга_  довольно доходчиво ответил Михаил Яковлевич Дымарский — ближе к концу передачи. Прослушать передачу можно здесь: https://www.radiorus.ru/brand/57203/episode/1211228

Comment: Передачу не смотрел, но предположил бы, что от слова *доходить* в значении *медленно умирать* (от голода, измождения и т.п.). В словаре Т.Ф.Ефремовой, значение 6.2: "Приходить в состояние крайнего истощения, изнеможения, безразличия." Объяснять это ребёнку - на ваше усмотрение. ))

Comment: @slava1947 Прослушала передачу — теперь мне проще будет выразиться. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Своё объяснение я выстроил бы следующим образом : нарисовал бы две черты и походил бы туда-обратно, объяснив значение слова "ходить". Затем,  одну черту  стёр бы, а до оставшейся дошёл бы и остановился, объяснив значение глагола "дойти". Доходяга  бредёт к своей "последней черте", и обратной дороги у него уже нет. Пока он к ней идёт, то есть находится в процессе (подобно трудящемуся трудяге и работающему работяге), он — доходяга . Когда путь его закончится — станет дошедшим.
П. С. Дети охотнее усваивают образы.

Answer (score 1):

Жизнь — это движение; когда движение становится невозможно, говорят, что *жизнь про**ход**ит* мимо или подходит к концу, и доходить до конца в этой жизни считается большой удачей. Доходяга — ограниченное в своём передвижении и действиях существо.

(*Под лежачий камень вода не течёт.* *Не потопаешь, не полопаешь.* *Волка ноги кормят.*)

Answer (score 0):

Ну если для ребенка... Вы, конечно, непонятную для ребенка (чтобы не сказать "ложную") параллель провели. Он не много ходит. Он уже свое отходил. И **дошел** до своего нынешнего плачевного состояния.

Другое дело - понять, что хотела сказать девочка. По своему опыты знаю, что дети задают такие вопрросы как правило не от понимания смысла слова, а выражая удивление кажущейся непоследовательностью языка, вытекающей из упрощенных, якобы адаптированных к деткому мышлению формулировок. Да язык еще не самое страшное. Помнится, я доводил до иступления взрослых вопросами, кто придумал такую глупость, как английский язык. Скажут какое0нибудь правило - а потом на него сотню исключений. А правило-то уже засело в мозгах как абсолют. Вот нечто подобное и могло возникнуть у девочки. В переводе с детского её "почему?" вполне может означать "Что ты мне голову морочишь своими объяснениями?".

Comment: Девочка услышала слово "доходяга" первый раз. Спросила: "Почему это доходяга?" Свое объяснение я начала со слов дворняга и бродяга. Потом мне показалось, что лучше подойдет рассказ о значении слов трудяга и работяга. Поэтому **ребенок** и сделал такой вывод (доходяга много ходит и доходит) и удивился. А я растерялась... Вот и стоит проблема: как объяснить семилетнему ребенку разницу между словами "ходит" и "доходит"?